# How to run your dataflow job in your local environment for debugging purpose

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, service-accounts

I am trying to debug the dataflow job by impersonating the GCP Service Account which has sufficient rights for accessing the buckets but I am getting some error related to classcastexception.
while debugging from local machine:-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableSet cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableSet is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Has anyone tried debugging the dataflow job of GCP in your local by impersonating service account?

Comment: Your job works with Dataflow runner ?

Comment: @Mazlum, In Cloud Yes.

Comment: How you launch your job ? Can you share the command line please ?

Comment: Can you confirm whether your service account  has roles/storage.admin [role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response.

I have managed to fix this issue by upgarding the jar for these

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I was using 1.14 in which it was a bug when trying to impersonate Service Account.
Now it has been resolved.